# Fit content to window height and show vertical scroll for inner divs

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I need to achieve the following layout:

[image]

In browser

[image]

The original layout is like this:

[image]

The content should be fitted to the browser window height, and if there are and div overflow the window i need to show a scrollbar to view the rest of content as shown in figure.

Here is jsfiddle link: [https://jsfiddle.net/5rwjseeq](https://jsfiddle.net/5rwjseeq/)

And this is the html and css:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.head-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background: #673AB7
}

.section {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: #f5f5dc;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.items {
  background: #FF5722;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.items .item {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFC107
}

.max {
  height: 100%;
}

.scrolly {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="page max">

  <div class="wrapper max">
    <div class="head-nav">
    </div>
    <div class="main-content max">
      <div class="section max">
        <div class="items">
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="content max scrolly">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
          publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
          printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
          of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
          has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem
          Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
          has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
          an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
          with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
          typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
          Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
          specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section max">
        <div class="items">
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="items">
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content max scrolly">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
          publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
          printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
          of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
          has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem
          Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
          has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
          an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
          with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
          typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
          Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
          specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The scroll in the content area is shown, but it is not fitted to the window height,

Is there any way to make it inside the window?

Comment: The main issue is that you're setting each `.content` to 100% of the parent height while not adjusting for the height of the `.items` which are also in the same parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a mix of the flexbox approach and Germano's answer.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw7x86qp/).

```
.main-content.max {
    height: calc (100% - 55px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 55px);  // cross browser compatibility
}

.section {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: #f5f5dc;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;  // cross browser compatibility
  flex-flow: column;  
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;  // cross browser compatibility
}

.content{
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1; // cross browser compatibility
    -ms-flex: 1; // cross browser compatibility
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.main-content.max {
    height: calc (100% - 55px);
}
```

Using calc you can subtract the height oh navbar at the body. This if the height of the navbar is always fixed.

Comment: Sorry the problem is the div class="items" see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3jwgb1a/ with .content.max {
    height: calc(100% - 44px);
} you can set corret height to column with one of this this.